# How to combine CustomMultiChildLayout with Draggable in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have some cards that need to be added to the canvas dynamically which leads me to change the approach from using Stack(Positioned) to CustomMultiChildLayout.

Here comes the problem. It's rather simple when using Stack(Positioned), I just setState to change the top and left of Positioned. But when it comes to CustomMultiChildLayout, how should I inform the delegate to relayout the card I just dragged and dropped?

```
Offset start = Offset.infinite;
Offset end = Offset.infinite;
var positions = <(Offset, Offset)>[];
GlobalKey? dragKey;
DraggableDetails? dragDetail;

class InfiniteCanvas extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const InfiniteCanvas({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _InfiniteCanvasState();
}

class _InfiniteCanvasState extends ConsumerState<InfiniteCanvas> {
  double cx = 1000.0;
  double cy = 1000.0;

  bool notSetStartPosition = true;
  var detailCardWidgets = <LayoutId>[];

  checkCallbackStatus(pos) {
    if (notSetStartPosition) {
      setEdgeStartPositionCallback(pos);
    } else {
      setEdgeEndPositionCallback(pos);
    }
  }

  setEdgeStartPositionCallback(pos) {
    setState(() {
      start = pos;
      notSetStartPosition = false;
    });
  }

  setEdgeEndPositionCallback(pos) {
    setState(() {
      end = pos;
      notSetStartPosition = true;
    });
  }

  setDragEnd(GlobalKey key, DraggableDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      dragKey = key;
      dragDetail = details;
    });
  }

  createDetailCardWidget() {
    final GlobalKey key = GlobalKey();
    var positionWidget = LayoutId(
      id: key,
      child: Draggable(
        feedback: DetailCardWidget(callback: checkCallbackStatus),
        onDragEnd: (details) {
          setDragEnd(key, details);
        },
        child: DetailCardWidget(callback: checkCallbackStatus),
      ),
    );

    setState(
      () {
        detailCardWidgets.add(positionWidget);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              InteractiveViewer(
                boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                onInteractionStart: (details) {},
                onInteractionUpdate: (details) {},
                onInteractionEnd: (details) {},
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                constrained: false,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 2 * cx,
                  height: 2 * cy,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      const Background(),
                      CustomMultiChildLayout(
                        delegate: DetailCardWidgetsDelegate(detailCardWidgets),
                        children: [
                          ...detailCardWidgets,
                        ],
                      ),
                      CustomPaint(
                        painter: EdgePainter(pos1: start, pos2: end),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 10,
                bottom: 10,
                child: Menu(
                  callback: createDetailCardWidget,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class EdgePainter extends CustomPainter {
  Offset pos1, pos2;

  EdgePainter({required this.pos1, required this.pos2});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;
    if (positions.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var i in positions) {
        if (i.$1 != Offset.infinite && i.$2 != Offset.infinite) {
          canvas.drawLine(i.$1, i.$2, paint);
        }
      }
    }

    if (pos1 != Offset.infinite && pos2 != Offset.infinite) {
      canvas.drawLine(pos1, pos2, paint);
      positions.add((pos1, pos2));
      start = Offset.infinite;
      end = Offset.infinite;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}

class DetailCardWidgetsDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  late List<GlobalKey> layoutIds;

  DetailCardWidgetsDelegate(List<LayoutId> list) {
    layoutIds = getLayoutId(list);
  }

  Offset childPosition = Offset.zero;

  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    for (GlobalKey id in layoutIds) {
      if (hasChild(id)) {
        final Size currentSize = layoutChild(
            id, BoxConstraints(maxWidth: size.width, maxHeight: size.height));
        positionChild(id, childPosition);
        childPosition += Offset(0, currentSize.height + 5);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) {
    if (dragKey != null) {
      if (hasChild(dragKey!)) {
        positionChild(dragKey!, dragDetail!.offset);
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  List<GlobalKey> getLayoutId(List<LayoutId> list) {
    return list.map((e) => e.id as GlobalKey).toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: after calling `setState` your delegate's `shouldRelayout` is called but you return `false` there

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to flutter. After changing shouldRelayout to true, how should I setState to change that card's childPosition? In Positioned, I can simply setState values like top and left. How do I do that with CustomMultiChildLayout?

Comment: replace `bool shouldRelayout(covariant MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => false` with `bool shouldRelayout(covariant MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) {print('shouldRelayout called'); return ...;}` and watch the logs - if you want your delegate to relayout then return `true` from that method

Comment: I just updated my code. I'm sorry if I am asking a dumb question. After dragging my card,  hasChild(dragKey!) is throwing an error: "The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#1153e]: Unexpected null value." Does it mean I cannot use draggable because the widget becomes null when dragging?